# Call a Windows Forms .NET EXE from PHP

Tags: php, .net, exe

I've seen many posts on stackoverflow but none of them helped.

I was (am) trying to run a .NET Windows Forms application (it doesn't contain any `forms/GUI/dialogs/so` but because of the nature of app it has to be Windows Forms). I tried `shell_exec()`, `exec()`, `passthru()`, etc. but all of them failed (they take infinitely long time and PHP Script never terminates)

Then, I tried running a simple C++ (unmanaged) console application - it WORKED and returned correct output and return code.

Then, I thought, maybe I could call this C++ EXE and let it further call a Windows application (i.e. in C++ using `SYSTEM("path_to_exe.exe");`)
It worked fine when I compiled it, but again,

when PHP calls this console (with new code to run a .NET EXE), PHP again takes infinte time and never stops. Why?

**Is there any one way I can successfully run my .NET EXE on Server from PHP?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: PHP is waiting for the process to exit and it does not do that. What kind of program are you running?

Comment: That's right. Thank you Jon!
I figured the process wasn't terminating correctly - now it did :)

Comment: Please don't change the question to "resolved".  Either post your own answer or accept on the posted answers by clicking on the check mark next to the post.

Answer (score 1):

"Is there any one way I can successfully run my .NET EXE on Server from PHP?" : Your EXE is already running !

So the problem is in your .NET EXE, i don't know what kind of EXE it is but you may use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) scripting to execute it and then close the process after X seconds, here's a snippet of code (don't forget to compile it):

```
Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Media Player Classic\mpc-hc.exe"); // You may use a relative path !
Sleep(5000); // Wait for 5 seconds
ProcessClose("mpc-hc.exe"); // Close the process
```

Comment: Hi, The problem in deed was in EXE - it wasn't terminating correctly and PHP for waiting for it to close. It has been fixed now. Thank you for your answer!